# how to clear error timer

Tags: asp.net

i have designing in my web page. i have use timer control in asp.net .the error are occur
 how to clear error how to run the timer

My code

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }

 public interface IScheduledItem

{

void AddEventsInInterval(DateTime Begin,
         DateTime End, ArrayList List);

    DateTime NextRunTime(DateTime time);
}
```

the error
he type or namespace name 'ArrayList' could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Collections to your project, and a using statement for System.Collections.

Comment: i have use but timer not display should i use any condition

Comment: The timer will run automatically when the page loads (if it is enabled) at the time specified in the control's Interval attribute.  You'll need to provide event handling methods for the events you want to handle.  [System.Web.UI.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the correct namespace like this:

`using System.Collections.ArrayList;`

Add this to the top of you file.